# how to create and place a semi transparent layer on top of another div in css

Tags: html, css

I have an image class named **image** and a div named **semitransparent**.

**i want to create a `semitransparent background` color in css, so that the image in image class can be seen through it**

How to create this semi transparent color in css?

```css
.semitransparent{
width:300px;
height:300px;
}

.image{
background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random);
width:300px;
height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="semitransparent">
<div class="image">
</div>
</div
```

Comment: @kraylog  is  it possible to give a semi transparent background color in css?

Comment: you can set the color with rgba

Comment: @Jupiter indeed it is, take a look at the question I linked

Answer (score 2):

You could use "position:absolute" to place the overlay - you'd need to find the position on the document and dimensions. But that can get annoying since you'd have to keep fixing it up as soon as the window dimensions change.
Have you heard of [css-filter:blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur)?
Just have a class

```
.blur{ filter: blur(4px) }
```

and then add/remove that class to your image. Oh, wait .. [not supported widely enough](https://caniuse.com/#search=blur) :-/

Depending on constraints you may have or could enforce there are a number of approaches to avoid having to fix up your overlay to keep matching the underlying elements position/dimensions.

```
.overlay{ position: absolute; width: 300; height: 300 }
.image{ position: relative; }
```

Then place the overlay inside the image DIV.

```
<div class="image"><div class="overlay"></div><img src="…" …></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using following code -

```
<div class="image">
    <div class="semitransparent">
    </div>
</div>

.semitransparent {
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
}

.image {
    background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/300/300/?random);
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Fiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/Lvhwmy31/

Comment: great explanation works fine

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, the way you've started it.. it is not possible to make child element above the parent with z-index, what would be an obvious try of course.

It's sort of a css ninja style anyway :)

You would rather place them both as sibilings, give parent a relative, and overlay an absolute, and you're done.

```
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child1"></div>
        <div class="child2"></div>
    </div>
    <style>
    .child1{
        background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random);
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
    }
    .child2{ 
        background-color: rgba(138, 43, 226, 0.6);
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
    }
    .parent {
        position: relative;
        height: 2000px;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: does rgba support on all browsers?

Comment: Yes. but not all versions though... 
https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

But you can use opacity as well... with a bit of extra stuff to cover them all 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/

Comment: Also, it is good to have seperate element for the overlay... you'll probably want to play with it on hover states or something similar. 

And parent will have a proper purpose, in case of containign some additional elements inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.full {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random) 0 0 no-repeat;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.full {
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}   

.full:hover .overlay-effect {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay-effect {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: rgba(259, 67, 95, 0.7);
  overflow:hidden;
}

.full a
 {
  color: #fff;
}

.full h3 {
  padding: 15px 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 368px) {
  .full{margin-bottom: 10px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="full">

</div>
</div
```

Answer (score 1):

check this code, Change "rgba" color while you want.

```
<div class="semitransparent">
<div class="image">
</div>
</div
.semitransparent{
width:100%;
height:100%;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

}

.image{
background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/300/300/?image=206);
width:300px;
height:300px;

}
```

Comment: great worked fine